# Can a service be added as a listener in Android?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am creating an android app, where I start a service in the background which should act as a listener for on Datachanged.BackgroundService is currently not doing anything, except to display log inside OnDatachanged.I would Like to do something like this.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent =new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
    startService(intent);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Log.d("Inside", "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside On connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.d("Inside", "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d("Inside", "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                }
            })
            // Request access only to the Wearable API
            .addApiIfAvailable(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    // This is what I want to achieve.Is there any way around for this?
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, BackgroundService.class);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Background Service extends intentService and Implements Data.ApiDataListener.

Comment: Do you want a Service that listens to wearable's datas change?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to implement. I also tried creating a new class that extend Wearable listener service.But the on datachanged of that class is never called.

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass `WearableListenerService` it will be called by the system when matching data is changed in the API. You don't need to call `addListener` in an `Activity` like this unless that's explicitly what you want to do.

I suggest you start with one of the sample apps (https://developer.android.com/samples/DataLayer seems a good choice) and build from there. The APIs do work.

Comment: These are the steps i followed to implement a wearableService
1) I created a new Class which extends Wearable Service, and overrides onDatachanged and Oncreate methods.
2) I declare the service in the manifest file 
3)I instantiated the service , using start activity. On doing so, the flow enters the "onconnected" method, However even After changing the data in the data layer, the Ondatachanged method is never called.What am I missing out?

Comment: There are a lot more potential points of failure than the three steps you list, unfortunately. This is why I suggested starting with one of the sample apps, as known working code, and modifying from there. Without having your entire project (+ devices) in front of me, I can't even guess where you've gone wrong.